# How can I log all user input?

Tags: logging

I am a Emacs newbie, so please forgive me if there is a obvious solution to this question. Is there a package which logs everything a user inputs into a emacs buffer? For example if I were to open a `test.txt` file and input `this is a test` could the input be logged into a seperate file with timestamps upon saving `test.txt`?

Answer (score 3):

`view-lossage` (bound to <kbd>C-h l</kbd> by default) is limited to a fixed number of events, and doesn't keep time stamps, but it might be good enough for your use case.  To store a longer log, you can try `open-dribble-file`.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761401 for a similar question.

Comment: OP: See the Emacs manual, node [Recording Input](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Recording-Input.html) for more info.

Comment: @Drew You mean the elisp manual.

Comment: @JeanPierre: Yes; sorry. Too late to edit that comment, I guess. Thx.